# How to get google drive apps on multiple accounts

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm running into what seems to be a serious usability problem for users trying to use a Google Drive app from more than one account. In order for an app to be able to use Drive APIs on a user's behalf, the user must install the associated Chrome Web Store app *while logged in as that user*. The problem is that the Chrome Web Store seems to look for an app being installed per browser, whereas the Drive API needs the app to be installed per user.

As far as I can tell, the only way to install the same app for multiple users in the same (Chrome) browser is to install with one user, then log in as the second user, uninstall the app (which the CWS says is already installed), and then reinstall it (so that Drive will mark the app as installed for the second user). This is a very confusing experience, because during this process the app and the CWS are sending the user mixed messages about whether the app is installed.

I'm not sure if there's a canonical app to test for system bugs like this. Is DrEdit live somewhere? But if you want to see the problem behavior in our implementation, install the [Graphing Calculator by Desmos.com](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bhdheahnajobgndecdbggfmcojekgdko) as one user, launch it and log in using google drive and verify that everything is working. Then log out from the app, and use https://accounts.google.com to log in to google as a different user, and try using the app again. The app will tell you that it isn't installed (that's what Drive's APIs are telling us) and direct you to the CWS, which claims that the app *is* installed.

Answer (score 3):

We are aware of the issue. And I agree this is a really bad experience for users using the same Browser (and the same Chrome session). One of the issue is that the account you are logged-into chrome can be different than the account you are logged into Google Web (Gmail, Chrome Web Store, Drive etc...) Therefore the Chrome Web Store has to make a choice to either use the apps's install status on the Browser or the Web Google account.

If you write an FAQ for your users maybe you can suggest that the most effective way to install the app for the second user is to simply install it using another browser like Firefox. Especially since Firefox won't be impacted by this issue because the app doesn't get installed on Firefox, only on the Drive account :)

The bug is filed internally, now we can only wait for it to be prioritized and fixed/sorted-out. We are also working on some other way for apps to have an install flow that doesn't involve the Chrome Web Store so that it will be less impacted by all of he Chrome Web Store/Chrome browser intricacies.

I'll make sure to ping our eng team on that issue again.